# What is a way to create a multi-key dictionary in .Net that only needs one key to be accessed?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I've searched around but have not found any good answer. So I'm asking here.

What I want is a good way to create a Dictionary that have 2 keys.

```
Dictionary<string (Key1), string(Key2), string(Value)> dict;
```

It should be accessible with one of the keys, let's say `dict["name"]` or `dict["email"]` and would return `(string, string, string)`. Both `Key1` and `Key2` have to be unique.

What I'm doing now is to create 4 dictionaries to map `(Key1, Value)`, `(Key2, Value)`, `(Key1, Key2)` and `(Key2, Key1)`

I think there will be some better way to do it?

Update:

`key1` does not need to be unique in `key2` and otherwise so the result could actually be a list of `(string, string, string)`

Comment: Keys are of string type, so why would you need 2 keys to access 1 value item?

Comment: You could possibly use one key lookup Dictionary and one value Dictionary.  Store both keys in the key lookup Dictionary with a single 'master key' value for each.  Use the 'master key' value in the value Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you model multiple items related to an entity as a class `Contact`,
you only need one `Dictionary<string, Contact>`

When you store your Contact instance, add it twice, for each property you want to index.

For example:

```
var c = new Contact(name, email);
d[c.Name] = c;
d[c.Email] = c;
```

Comment: Sorry for not clearify the question. It could be for example ("abc@mail.com", "contact@mail.com", "company") and ("abc", "abc@mail.com", "abc")

Comment: Still not clear. I'm not sure i understand your notation using parentheses. What kind of object are you trying to find?

Comment: Try to learn about basic object oriented concepts. In addition, try to specify your requirements in non-programming terminology.

Comment: What I mean is each name in the name list is unique and each mail in the mail list is unique, also each mail is uniquely assigned to a name, but it does not necessarily mean that the mail list cannot conatin an entry with exact the same value as a name but is not assigned to that name. Let's say we have two pairs of data the first pair is: Name = abc, Mail = "abc@mail.com" the 2nd pair: Name="abc@mail.com" and Mail = "another@mail.com".

Comment: So with you pattern by storing all keys in the same dictionary would either crash by adding duplicate key or corrupt the data

Comment: It won't crash because indexer [] on dictionary allows replacement, that's different from the `Add` method. Yes, it would corrupt data as per your clarification, so you need to store multiple values by each key in some data structure. If you dont have objects with unique keys, and just need to store tuples it can be a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<(string name, string email)>`.

Answer (score 1):

If I had a database of Person and I wanted to provide some kind of indexed search, I could store all the search terms in one dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Person>> d = new Dictionary<string, List<Person>>();

//let me all them a, b and c so I can easily refer to them later in comments 
Person a = new Person("John", "jsmith@hotmail.com");
Person b = new Person("John", "johnno@email.com");
Person c = new Person("Jane", "jsmith@hotmail.com");

//you'll probably have your Persons in some kind of array
Person[] ps = new[]{a, b, c};

//index the Persons
foreach(Person p in ps){
  if(!d.ContainsKey(p.Name))
    d[p.Name] = new List<Person>();

  d[p.Name].Add(p);//add to list inside dictionary

  if(!d.ContainsKey(p.Email))
    d[p.Email] = new List<Person>();

  d[p.Email].Add(p);//add to list inside dictionary
}

//returns a list containing person a and b
d["John"]

//returns a list containing person a and c
d["jsmith@hotmail.com"]
```

You'll always get a List back if there is a search hit, and it might contain one item:

```
d["Jane"] //a list containing only person c
```

or more than one item (example for John above).

If the result of d["some text"] is null, there was no hit on the search

To make searching case insensitive, lowercase the names and emails when Adding the person in the List:

```
d[person.NameOrEmail.ToLower()].Add(person);
```

And use a lowercase when keying the dictionary:

```
d["john"]
```